# AVFoundation For Scanning

Tags: avfoundation

I am using AVFoundation for scanning PDF417 bar codes.  I have compared how quickly my scanner detects and returns the results to some of the commercial products.  The commercial products are twice as fast.  I am using the following to configure the video camera:

```
if ([self.device lockForConfiguration:&error])
{
    if (self.device.isAutoFocusRangeRestrictionSupported)
        self.device.autoFocusRangeRestriction = AVCaptureAutoFocusRangeRestrictionNear;
    if ([self.device isFocusModeSupported: AVCaptureFocusModeContinuousAutoFocus])
        self.device.focusMode = AVCaptureFocusModeContinuousAutoFocus;

    if( self.device.isSmoothAutoFocusSupported )
        self.device.smoothAutoFocusEnabled = YES;

    if (self.device.isLowLightBoostEnabled)
        self.device.automaticallyEnablesLowLightBoostWhenAvailable = YES;

    [self.device unlockForConfiguration];
}
```

Are there other configurations that I can use to improve scanning?  Is it better to set the video to the highest quality and frame rate or is low better?  Would setting the White Balance improve the scan recognition ability?

Comment: Are you sure it's the proper camera settings that your solution lacks compared to the commercial ones? What about smarter/faster computer vision techniques?

Comment: It is very possible that the commercial ones have custom written decoding logic.  If you know of anywhere to get examples of such logic I would appreciate it.